# Windows Visual C++ 2019 trying to pass preprocessor varible (-D in linux ) error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

im doing simple port from Linux to windows, now in Linux I pass simple
-DVERSION=1 to be able to get the value in preprocessor macro :
for example :

```
#define APP_NAME  "MyApp " VERSION
```

in windows when i set the VERSION value in :
Configuration Properties, C/C++, Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions
as :

```
VERSION=1
```

I'm getting :

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'constant'
```

also when if the VERSION define in other places like :

```
 char *message = (char*)"MyApp " VERSION "\0";
```

getting the same :

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'
```

when i mouse point on the VERSION  definition i do see that it set to 1

Comment: I see the same error with gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/766n4P please provide a [mre]

Comment: Adding quotes works for both MSVC and gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/Pqz7x9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
VERSION=1
```

then `VERSION` expands to the *integer* literal `1`, which means your statement is as this:

```
char *message = "MyApp " 1 "\0";
```

This is not valid, as you can't concatenate string literals with integer literals. For this to work you need to define `VERSION` as a *string* literal:

```
VERSION="1"
```

---

As for the `APP_NAME` macro, you have a similar issue there. One solution is the same as for above, to define `VERSION` as a string. But another is to use the poreprocessor concatenation operator `##`:

```
#define APP_NAME  "MyApp " ## VERSION
```

Or use the preprocessor "stringify" operator `#`:

```
#define APP_NAME  "MyApp " #VERSION
```